# Windows update doesn't list update details, only the number of updates

Tags: windows-vista, windows-update

My system is Vista Business 32 bits SP2.

When I click "Windows update", I can see there are 2 available optional updates. If I click the link "2 optional updates are available" to see what the updates are, I get:

http://leodip.s3.amazonaws.com/windows_update2.PNG

The details about the updates are EMPTY. Any idea why this is happening? It doesn't happen only with optional updates, but with critical updates as well.

I would like to fix this, so I can see what the updates are.

Answer (score 3):

Forcefully killing the respective explorer.exe process and retrying fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it's happening so I can't help with that, but in the interim have you tried using the windows update site?

Perhaps one of the updates fixes this problem :)

Comment: If I go to the Windows update site, it asks me to use the Windows update applet in Control Panel.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the WindowsUpdate.log in your Windows directory. That might give you a clue as to what is going on.

Answer (score -1):

Is this your personal computer, or a corporate asset.  That link would appear to be directed at a cloud based server at Amazon, which I don't believe MS uses to distribute patches (I could be wrong).

Comment: That's just a link to a picture that displays the incorrect behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  I misread the problem.